# Applying built-in animate-spin to hover state using tailwind

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

This is the element I'm trying to apply the spin anim to:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-6 w-6 inline hover:animate-spin" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" >
    <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} ... />
                
</svg>
```

As I hover over the element nothing happens. If I remove the hover pseudo class it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to generate hover variant. As the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/animation) says:

> By default, only responsive variants are generated for animation utilities.
>
> You can control which variants are generated for the animation utilities by modifying the animation property in the variants section of your tailwind.config.js file.
>
> For example, **this config will also generate hover and focus variants**:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    variants: {
      extend: {
        // ...
       animation: ['hover', 'focus'],
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I read this part of the docs and I did that. Then changed the applied class to hover-animate-spin. I think I was a bit too focused and should have been using hover:animate-spin. Will try it later when I get home.

Comment: Ok, I had 2 problems. 1) to access the anim you should do it wth the prefix animate, and 2) The above lines must be added to the tailwind.config.js to let craco generate the needed clases. Thanks!